# How to change color of selected annotation MKMapView

Tags: swift, mapkit, mapkitannotation

I am trying to change the color of the selected annotation, annotations have properties .selectedGlyphImage but not .selectedGlypgColor, how I can change the color of the selected annotation?

Code how I add annotations:

func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {

```
let annotationView = MKMarkerAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: "MyMarker")
annotationView.markerTintColor = .clear

annotationView.glyphImage = UIImage(named: "MapIcon")
annotationView.glyphTintColor = Constant.Colors.secondaryMainColor

return annotationView
```

}

Code of selected annotations :

```
        for i in self.mapView.annotations {
            
            let marker = i.coordinate
            let scrollableElement = arrayOfHouse[index].coordinate
            
            if (marker.latitude == scrollableElement.latitude && marker.longitude == scrollableElement.longitude) {
                    print("* \(String(describing: i.title))")

                    // BELOW I select annotaion but don't know how to change color of selected annotations, what I can do in this situatio?

                mapView.selectAnnotation(i, animated: true)
                annotationForCollectionView = i
                

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: How does a bot tell which annotation has been selected?

Comment: @ElTomato I am select annotation by this line of code "mapView.selectAnnotation(i, animated: true)" where "i" are is correct annotation

Comment: So how does your bot tell which annotation has been selected?  Is it able to tell one annotation from another with a unique identifier or something?

Comment: @ElTomato I can select annotation which I want, programmatically or by click on that annotation If I want to select annotation programmatically I use coordinates of that annotation but my problem is that I can't change the color of the selected annotation, and it doesn't matter how I will try to select this annotation, are you have any idea how I can change the color of selected annotation?

Comment: I'm not asking you if you can or how you select an annotation.

Comment: @ElTomato Ok, then I don't fully understand your question, what do you mean, can you explain? The first time you are asked me "How does a bot tell which annotation has been selected?" but I don't have "bot", all action will be doing the user.